# How Do I Re-Write This MySQL Query to Include a Parameter?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

**Good evening,**

I've been working at this all day today to no avail.  I'm using the code below to take user input in a textbox and search through the database (as the user types) and present the results in a ListView control.  It works as-is, but I know it's insecure because it's not parametized.  I know how to add the parameter to the MySQLCommand object but can't figure out how to add it to the query.  Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

**HERE'S MY CODE:**

```
Private Sub TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSearch.TextChanged

    Dim dbConn As New MySqlConnection(String.Format("Server={0};Port={1};Uid={2};Password={3};Database=accounting", FormLogin.ComboBoxServerIP.SelectedItem, My.Settings.DB_Port, My.Settings.DB_UserID, My.Settings.DB_Password))
    Dim dbQuery As String = ""
    Dim dbCmd As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dbReader As MySqlDataReader
    Dim a, b, c, d, f, g

    Try
        dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
            "WHERE nameCOMPANY OR accountNumber LIKE '%" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "%' " & _
            "ORDER BY nameCOMPANY ASC"
        dbConn.Open()
        dbCmd = New MySqlCommand(dbQuery, dbConn)
        dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()

        ListViewRecords.Items.Clear()

        Do While dbReader.Read()

            a = (dbReader.Item("ccID").ToString())
            b = (dbReader.Item("accountNumber").ToString())
            c = (dbReader.Item("nameCOMPANY").ToString())
            d = DecryptCard(dbReader.Item("ccNumber").ToString())
            f = (dbReader.Item("ccExpireMonth").ToString())
            g = (dbReader.Item("ccExpireYear").ToString())

            Dim item As ListViewItem = ListViewRecords.Items.Add(a)
            item.SubItems.Add(b)
            item.SubItems.Add(c)
            item.SubItems.Add(d)
            item.SubItems.Add(f)
            item.SubItems.Add(g)
        Loop
        dbReader.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("A DATABASE ERROR HAS OCCURED" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & ex.Message & vbCrLf & _
                            vbCrLf + "Please report this to the IT/Systems Helpdesk at Ext 131.")
    End Try
    dbConn.Close()
    dbCmd.Dispose()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming your issue is the wildcards not working correctly. This does not work as the parameter cannot be enclosed in quotes.

```
dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
        "WHERE nameCOMPANY OR accountNumber LIKE '%?ParameterName%' " & _
        "ORDER BY nameCOMPANY ASC"
```

To fix, you can concat the wildcards into your parameter first and then insert it into your query.

```
Dim parameter = "%" & TextBoxSearch.Text & "%"

dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
        "WHERE nameCOMPANY OR accountNumber LIKE ?ParameterName " & _
        "ORDER BY nameCOMPANY ASC"
```

Comment: Thanks Tomcat, unfortunately it didn't work for me.  While no exceptions are thrown, the DO WHILE statement is being skipped when I modify the query as you suggested.  I tried doing this instead and got the same results:  LIKE CONCAT('%', @search_string, '%') with the parameter define as:  dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@search_string", TextBoxSearch.Text).  Any other suggestions?

Comment: please accept my apologies.  I made a mistake in my variable declaration.  I did Dim parameter AS String = instead of what you provided.  All is good now and it works, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like:

```
    dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM cc_master INNER JOIN customer " & _
        "ON customer.accountNumber = cc_master.customer_accountNumber " & _
        "WHERE nameCOMPANY OR accountNumber LIKE '%' + ? + '%' " & _
        "ORDER BY nameCOMPANY ASC"

    dbConn.Open()
    dbCmd.Connection = dbConn
    dbCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    dbCmd.CommandText = dbQuery
    dbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBoxSearch.Text)
    dbReader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader()
```

However, I think you would probably be better with a stored procedure and pass parameters to that http://www.mysqltutorial.org/stored-procedures-parameters.aspx

Comment: Remou, thanks for your response.  I haven't mastered Stored Procedures yet so haven't tried that approach.  In any case, your suggestion didn't work for me - not sure why.  I actually got an exception telling me to check my query.

Comment: It was tested with SQL Server, not MySQL, so that might be the problem.

Comment: thanks, I really do appreciate the assistance.  Tomcat's suggestion did the trick.